# How to make Magento as my sub website?

Tags: magento-1.8, url-rewrite

I managed to move my magento store from my **localhost** to my **live server**, following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762090/how-do-i-transfer-a-local-magento-install-onto-my-live-server).

However, I have an unconventional folder structure how I run my **main website** and **magento website**. For instance,

This is the structure for my main website,

```
bin/
core/
local/
index.php
```

And I just want the magento system to be my **sub 'website'** as my webstore, so I keep all my magento files into `bin/store/`. And for this reason, all my images that I uploaded to `wysiwyg/` don't work anymore - they are not displayed on screen anymore.

Also, the links with url rewrite are not working anymore too, for instance,

http://store.helloworld.com/wine/

I will get,

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time
>   the error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this
>   error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log. Apache Server at store.argenties.com Port 80

Any ideas how I can fix these two problems?

Comment: put your Magento installation in /bin/store and make your server look for /bin/store whenever it comes across `http://subdomain.yourdomain.com/`

Comment: I did set my server to look for `/bin/store` but still no good.

Comment: but are you able to go to your Magento store? Does it give you that 500 error right away?

Comment: no 500 error. I can see the index page of my magento store. but i get the error in my question above when I click on the link on this index page, for instance the link to http://store.helloworld.com/wine/

Comment: have you tried reindexing URL's?

Comment: I can't access my backoffice from my liveserver via this link anymore - http://store.helloworld.com/admin/ - I get the same error above - so I can't reindexing URL's.

Comment: What can I do to reindex the urls?

Comment: either delete them from the DB, or reindex by hand if you can access your website by SSH then `php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url` from your Magento root folder. But I can't guarantee it'll give you access to your backend. What does Apache say in its error/access logs?

Comment: it says `Internal Server Error` - just as in my question.

Comment: which table in the DB I should look for to delete them then?

Comment: `core_url_rewrite` I *guess* but as I said, I can't promise this will do any change, I suggest you go and make a backup of your DB before doing this. I'm pretty sure this is server related, as I don't see what else could be wrong.
*One more thing* you could try, go to `core_config_data` in your DB, then change the values of `web/secure/base_url` and `web/unsecure/base_url` to whatever your new URL is compared to your localhost

Comment: `core_config_data` - I have done that part.

Comment: well, I'm out of ideas for today Sir, I'll come back and check tomorrow, hope someone comes across your question and has the answer

Comment: no problem. thanks for the help anyway. :D

Answer (score 1):

The images may have the path of your localhost. Please check in code view in wysiwyg editor what path your images have.

The Internal Server Error may be related to a wrong/incompatible setting in the .htaccess. Did you change anything there?

Comment: It is the problem from the live server actually. AVOID godaddy at any cost!

Comment: So did you switch the hoster and now it's working? general note here: most of the shared hosters will have problems with Magento (performance, special settings)

Comment: Yes it runs fast on siteground hosting.